# Reading lines in txt file and comparing in Java(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, text

So im trying to read 60k+ lines text file with single word on each line (dictionary) and compare it with given word. I need to do it as fast as possible. Yhe current script takes 5 seconds to run which is really bad result:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("dictionary", "raw", getPackageName())));
while(in.hasNext()){
        String word = in.next();
        if(word.equals(some_word)){
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(word);
        }
    }
    TextView timeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
```

Im searching for a best results possible while keeping a txt file in /raw folder of a project.

Im thinking about BufferedReader but have no idea how to pass it my txt file

Comment: Isn't this obtaining always the same object? TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)

Comment: no, it is happening only when the if statement is true which occurs only once. If you mean that i dont have break method to exit loop, this script is just for testing. For 'some_word' i use one of the last words to get maximum time it will take to run

Comment: Avoid `Scanner`. `Scanner` is slow. Even though you're using `BufferedReader`, it wouldn't be enough. It would probably takes 200~300 m/s. If you're really want it fast, you need to encode/format the text file, e.g. all `-ing`, less important words must be removed. At the end of the day, this requires a lot of braincells.

Comment: so thanks god i dont need to encode it) I figured out how to implement 'BufferedReader' with Android internal app storage and got maximum of 50ms on the last word in file which is enough for my case. Going to update the question with the new version

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using BufferedString.

Here is the way i implemented it, takes about 50ms to scroll trough the entire list of words:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("dictionary", "raw", getPackageName()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.equals("some_word")){
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                textt.setText(line);
                break;
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```